# How to call a complex function with multiple inputs parameters and multiple output parameters using Nethereum in .net core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, ethereum, smartcontracts

Hello these days i'm creating a decentralised web api using .net core 2.2 and nethereum library.
Now I'm in a critical situation because when I try to call a function of the smart contract which having multiple inputs and outputs parameter through nethereum following error occurred.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> NotSupportedException: System.Int32 is not supported
>
> Nethereum.ABI.Decoders.StringTypeDecoder.Decode(byte[] encoded, Type
>   type)

I google about this but any of article which I found was not help for me to resolve this. So if anyone can help me I'm highly appreciate.

---

**Here my smart contract function**

```
function test(string memory x, uint256 y, bool z) public view returns(string memory _x,
    uint256 _y, bool _z){
            return(x, y, z);
    }
```

**Here is my approach to call the function using .net core**

```
[FunctionOutput]
    public class Test : IFunctionOutputDTO
    {
        [Parameter("string", "_x", 1)]
        private string X { get; set; }

        [Parameter("uint256", "_y", 2)]
        private bool Y { get; set; }

        [Parameter("bool", "_z", 3)]
        private bool Z { get; set; }


    [Function("test")]
    public class TestFunction : FunctionMessage
    {
        [Parameter("string", "x", 1)]
        public string X { get; set; }
        [Parameter("uint256", "y", 2)]
        public string Y { get; set; }
        [Parameter("bool", "z", 3)]
        public bool Z { get; set; }
    }
```

**Inside my service I call to the contract**

```
public async Task<Test> Test(TestBody body)
        {
            var dataset = new TestFunction
            {
                X = body.x,
                Y = body.y,
                Z = body.z
            };
            var testHandler = web3.Eth.GetContractQueryHandler<TestFunction>();
            var response = await testHandler.QueryDeserializingToObjectAsync<Test>(dataset, contractAddress);
            return response;
        }
```

In here **body** is just the object of request body mapped class with

```
public string x; 
public BigInteger y; 
public bool z;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how this library works or smart contracts for that matter, but just looking at your parameters and types, it looks like you may have the wrong type set on your DTO:

```
    [Parameter("uint256", "_y", 2)]
    private bool Y { get; set; }
```

Shouldn't this be an unsigned int?

Comment: Thank you for replying and I have corrected that but still the error message occur

Answer (score 0):

I also think you may have the wrong types set on your DTO and functionMessage. Uint256 should be used with BigInteger.

```
[FunctionOutput]
    public class Test : IFunctionOutputDTO
    {
        [Parameter("string", "_x", 1)]
        private string X { get; set; }

        [Parameter("uint256", "_y", 2)]
        private BigInteger Y { get; set; }

        [Parameter("bool", "_z", 3)]
        private bool Z { get; set; }


    [Function("test")]
    public class TestFunction : FunctionMessage
    {
        [Parameter("string", "x", 1)]
        public string X { get; set; }
        [Parameter("uint256", "y", 2)]
        public BigInteger Y { get; set; }
        [Parameter("bool", "z", 3)]
        public bool Z { get; set; }
    }
```